# Routing behavior not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following routes variable defined in my app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = 
[
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/users', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
  { path: 'users',  component: UsersComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent }
];
```

With this current configuration, when I submit http://localhost:3000/users, the browser redirects to http://localhost:3000/users/users and then displays the user list binding in the html as expected.

However, something seems off kilter for the browser to redirect from /users to /users/users.  If I remove the th first route config with the redirectTo attribute then the browser stays on /users without redirecting to /users/users.  However, in this scenario, the user list binding doesn't display as expected.

Any idea what might be causing the redirect to /users/users?  Any idea how I can keep the browser on /users and get the user list binding to properly display at this uri?

Comment: Which version of Angular2 are you on?  And which version of the router?

Comment: "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
"@angular/router": "~3.1.1"

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code at first glance, are you importing using `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],`?

Comment: yes: @NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you haven't set your base href. The docs suggest adding something like `<base href="/">` into your index.html file but I found that there were too many side-effects to that approach. I prefer to import `APP_BASE_HREF` from '@angular/common' and pass this as a provider in your `app.module.ts`: `providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' } ... ]`

Comment: Another interesting piece of information is that a similar pattern occurs with each route that I attempt.  I'm building this app off of the angular.io tour of heroes app so I have a route defined for /heroes and /dashboard. http://localhost:3000/dashboard redirects to http://localhost:3000/dashboard/users and displays a list of user info on the page.  Same weird behavior with http://localhost:3000/heroes.

Comment: Another interesting piece of information is that whatever is included in this config item determines the final redirect: { path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' }.  This config item had pointed to /users in my original post.  I changed default path to '/heroes' as shown in the code above and now all routes get appended with '/heroes' at the end and the browser subsequently redirects to '/heroes'

Comment: That points towards not having the base href setup, see my comment above. Is something like that implemented in your code?

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  That was the problem.  I had copied over index.html from the toh app so I had assumed that it was configured correctly and the page did include special code to set base href: <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>.  However, the was not setting  base href = "/" hence the failure.

Comment: Perfect, glad you got it resolved! added a formal answer for posterity in case someone else faces the same issue ( with a bit of a longer explanation of the alternative to setting the html tag ).

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Setting base tag

In order to get the router working properly a base href needs to be defined somehow for the app. The docs recommend [adding a base element](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href) to the head of your index.html file, such as:

`<base href="/">`

### Option 2: Setting a provider

This can be a bit dangerous however as it has [(potentially unexpected) side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1889898/1380739) on anchor tags, empty href tags, etc, etc. It also breaks inline svg sprites... which was a major part of our app's UI. If you want to make the router work but not break a lot of things you can actually define the base href elsewhere, like so:

```
// ... other imports
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    
    // ... other pieces of ngModule
    
    providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }
    ],
    
    // ... other pieces of ngModule
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor() {}
}
```

As a basic example. It's a bit hard to find in the documentation but is a good workaround to get things going without messing with everything else.